# Writing a summation as the ratio of polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Write the sum
>   $\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \frac { { (-1) }^{ k }\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right)  }{ { k }^{ 3 }+9{ k }^{ 2 }+26k+24 }  } $ in the form $\frac { p(n) }{ q(n) }$, where $p(n)$ and $q(n)$ are polynomials with integral coefficients.

I am not able to progress in this problem.Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Start by splitting by partial fractions after factorising $k^3+9k^2+26k+24=(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \frac { { (-1) }^{ k }\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right)  }{ { k }^{ 3 }+9{ k }^{ 2 }+26k+24 }  } = \sum _{k=0}^{n} {\frac { (-1)^k \dbinom{n}{k}}{2(k+2)} }-\sum _{k=0}^{n} {\frac { (-1)^k \dbinom{n}{k}}{(k+3)} }+\sum _{k=0}^{n} {\frac { (-1)^k \dbinom{n}{k}}{2(k+4)} }$

Now consider the binomial theorem,

$x(1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \dbinom{n}{k}x^{k+1}$

Now integrating both sides from 0 to 1
$\int_{0}^{1} x(1-x)^n = \sum _{k=0}^{n} {\frac { (-1)^k \dbinom{n}{k}}{2(k+2)} } $

similarly for the other parts.

so the sum is equal to

$ \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{0}^{1}( x(1-x)^n -2x^2(1-x)^n +x^3(1-x)^n) \right)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{n+3}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{n+2} =\frac{1}{2(n+4)(n+3)} $